# How to add a method source to an existing java file with JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing a simple eclipse plugin, which is a code generator. User can choose an existing method, then generate a new test method in corresponding test file, with JDT.

Assume the test files is already existed, and it's content is:

```
public class UserTest extends TestCase {
    public void setUp(){}
    public void tearDown(){}
    public void testCtor(){}
}
```

Now I have generate some test code:

```
/** complex javadoc */
public void testSetName() {
    ....
    // complex logic
}
```

What I want to do is to append it to the existing `UserTest`. I have to code:

```
String sourceContent = FileUtils.readFileToString("UserTest.java", "UTF-8");
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(content.toCharArray());
CompilationUnit testUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

String newTestCode = "public void testSetName() { .... }";

// get the first type
final List<TypeDeclaration> list = new ArrayList<TypeDeclaration>();
testUnit .accept(new ASTVisitor() {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
        list.add(node);
        return false;
    }
});
TypeDeclaration type = list.get(0);

type.insertMethod(newTestCode); // ! no this method: insertMethod
```

But there is no such a method `insertMethod`.

I know two options now:

1. Do not use `jdt`, just to insert the new code to the test file, before last `}`
2. use `testUnit.getAST().newMethodDeclaration()` to create a method, then update it.

But I don't like these two options, I hope there is something like `insertMethod`, which can let me append some text to the test compilation unit, or convert the test code to a MethodDeclaration, then append to the test compilation unit.

---

**UPDATE**

I see [nonty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697220/how-to-add-a-method-source-to-an-existing-java-file-with-jdt/6697997#6697997), and found there are two `CompilationUnit` in jdt. One is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit`, another is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit`. I used the second one, and nonty used the first one.

I need to supplement my question: At first I want to create a eclipse-plugin, but later I found it hard to create a complex UI by swt, so I decided to create a web app to generate the code. I copied those jdt jars from eclipse, so I can just use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit`.

Is there a way to use `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit` outside eclipse?

Comment: In fact I always use the interfaces! In this case, it is `ICompilationUnit`. Which is implemented by `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit`. The `...core.dom...` versions provide a much finer grained representation for Java and is typically used in re-factoring...

Comment: @Tonny, is it possible to use `ICompilationUnit` outside eclipse? How to get an instance of it?

Comment: Not sure... You can easily check by creating a new launch configuration, add the`...jdt.core` plug-in, and then `Add Required`. Then check if `org.eclipse.ui` or `org.eclipse.core.runtime` are included. If so, then it is unlikely - though still possible - that it will work outside a full Eclipse environment...

Comment: @Tonny, I copied those jars to a non-plugin java project, but I don't find a way to convert a java file to a `ICompilationUnit`. At last, I used another java parser `qdox` to parse and generate sources. Thank for your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with

```
...
String newTestCode = "public void testSetName() { .... }";
IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();

IMethod method = testUnit.getTypes[0].createMethod(newTestCode, null, false, monitor);
```

You can even specify where to add the new method and whether to "overwrite" any exiting method.

Comment: where is the `createMethod`? What's the type? I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

JavaCore has a method to create a CompilationUnit from a given IFile.

```
IFile file;    
JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(file);
```